Dummit and Foote example on radical ideal over rationals
This is about the example on top of page 702 (Section 15.3) in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra (third edition), which I believe to contain an error:

Suppose $W = \mathcal{Z}(J)$ with $J = (u^3 - u v^2 + v^3) \in \mathbb{Q}[u, v]$. The polynomial $x^3 - x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $f = u^3 - u v^2 + v^3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[u, v]$. Hence $\operatorname{rad} J = J$ and $\mathcal{I}(W) = J$.

I agree that $\operatorname{rad} J = J$ and with the explanation of this fact. But $W = \mathcal{Z}(J)$ is defined to be the subset of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ on which every $f \in J$ vanishes (p. 658) so we should have $W = \{(0, 0)\}$ and $\mathcal{I}(W) = (u, v)$. Am I missing something?
I found a relatively recently updated errata for the book but this issue is not included.

I think this is indeed a mistake in the book. The claim that $\mathcal{I}(W) = \operatorname{rad}(J)$ relies on the Nullstellensatz, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an algebraically closed field.
